# Number of different functions

Tags: functions

Suppose that $A$ has exactly $m$ elements and $B$ has exactly $n$ elements. How many different functions are there from $A$ to $B$?

The answer is given by $n^m$ but i don't know how to get that

And also, how to know the number of injective and surjective function from $A$ to $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each function A to B, you can pick n ways to send each element of A to an element of B. There are m elements of A, so it is $n \times \ldots \times n$ (m times) $=n^m$.

For an injection, you need one-to-one. So, you have to pick m different elements of B (note that n must be at least m for an injection to exist), and then assign the m elements without repeating them. So, you can pick m elements in $\binom{n}{m}$ ways, and assign the elements once you fix the m elements in $m!$ ways, so the answer is $\binom{n}{m} m!$ (what quantity is this?)

For a surjection, you need all the elements of B to be the output of the function for some element of A. This is a bit trickier and I leave it to you as an exercise -- use the inclusion exclusion principle. If you can't figure it out, look at "63.29 Surjections from an m-Set to an n-Set
F. Gerrish
The Mathematical Gazette
Vol. 63, No. 426 (Dec., 1979), pp. 259-261" (http://www.jstor.org/stable/3618041) or [this link](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgax/5-functions.pdf).